# Testing association in R

Tags: r

The question is: Do mortality and water hardness statistically associated for all the 61 cities?

Package = HSAUR data("water")

How can i test association in R? I hope someone can help me with this!

Comment: Second on google search. https://rdrr.io/cran/HSAUR/man/water.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have nothing too do at work due to corona, so here goes.

```
library('HSAUR')
data("water", package = "HSAUR")
plot(mortality ~ hardness, data = water, 
     col = as.numeric(water$location))

lm <- lm(mortality ~ hardness + as.factor(location), data = water)
summary(lm)
```

Comment: Location is south north not all 61 cities though?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: Does this prove statistical association with all the 61 cities in the data under variable town?

Comment: Since city is the observation you cant use that as a grouping variable. It shows that there is a association between water hardness, location of the city and mortality rate.

Comment: Okey thanks, can u help me with one more question that i need to answer? That is - Do both variables, mortality and water hardness, also statistically associated in north and south cities, respectively?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Basically i have a task to asnwer theese 2 questions with hypothesis and prove it with R codes and plots, and theese 2 are the questions. 1) in the topic 2) in the comment i wrote.

Comment: And i am pretty much stuck on theese 2 questions and can't fiqure out how to answer them with providing R code and plots.

Comment: I have answered both in my post. You can see an association between water hardness, location of the city and mortality rate. If you run the code I provided and read the output, and interpret it, you will find the answer to both questions.

Comment: I already ran the code and see the output, I will try to understand that now and try to answer both questions, thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Please add my post as a solution if it helped you :)

Comment: Basically i added regression line and will explain that - Yes the Water hardness and mortality are associated with all 61 cities as there is a negative corelation meaning that mortality is higher in the cities with low water hardness level. Can that be right?

Comment: That seems correct to me. As for the second question look at the estimates for the factor "location" from the summary(lm).

Comment: as.factor(location)South = -176.7108
1st I don't get Location North estimate
2nd I sadly don't know how to use the estimate to answer my question :(

Comment: That line shows the y-intercept for the different groups. It shows south compared to north. So what can you say between the two different locations based on the information?

Comment: That the variables mortality and the hardness are not statistically associated with the south and north location because the estimate is in a such a big negative?

Comment: Not true. If you look at the p-value its well below the "standars" 0.05. What it tells you is that when controlling for water hardness south has a mean lower mortality rate of ~177 compared to north. So location of the city as an association with mortality when controlled for water hardness. Furthermore, water hardness has an association with mortality when controlled for location. This since both variables are in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the model is the plot right?

Comment: No problem :) The plot is a visualisation of the model. The linear regression  "lm <- lm(mortality ~ hardness + as.factor(location), data = water) " is the model.

Comment: Okay thanks, and have u ever wrote a data analysis report?